Nuxt router prefix changes url for _nuxt folder request
I added a prefix on my nuxt config.
Everything works fine, but when my app is published online, when the app starts and build, the local fetch for _nuxt directory are wrong (I have 4 url that fetch data from /_nuxt), return an 404 and looks like the following :
https://app.my-example-cloud.com/prefix/_nuxt/8925d74.js

What I would like would be the same URL without the /prefix., because my prefix is not working for inner folder/files inside the project.
Just over this request in my debug console, network tab, I can see other url fetched that doesn't have the prefix in their url. The request is therefore returning 200
I don't understand how to prevent prefix to be used for any fetch inside the project folder.
What I don't understand also is that I have others fetch that are located inside project folder (EG : base.url.com/third_party/plugins1.js) that does not contain the prefix in their urls
I've checked the Nuxt 2 docs, but I have anything helpful.
Post I've checked : add router prefix
Why nuxt build folder use prefix and other request does not ?
How to prevent this behaviour ?
